# Why is a single "D" character disappearing in Jenkins pipeline step?

Tags: windows, jenkins, cmd

I'm trying to figure out why a single character is disappearing in a Jenkins pipeline Windows Batch step.

Here is the "Pipeline Steps" view, which shows that the command starts with `FOR /D` (ignore the errorlevel check, I noticed too late that it is broken):

[image: Jenkins "Pipeline Steps"]

Here is the console, which has the same command, but without the `D`:

[image]

To be honest I'm a bit stumped by this, this does not correspond to the usual escaping issues (the `/` is not an escape character). So, what gives? Anybody has any clue? Should I call Georges Perec?

A minimal pipeline that exhibits the same issue (disappearing `D`) but seems to work fine is:

```
pipeline {
   agent any

   stages {
      stage('Hello') {
         steps {
            deleteDir()
            bat 'md dst'
            bat 'md src'
            bat 'md src\\test-doc-1'
            bat 'md src\\test-doc-2'
            bat 'md src\\test-3'
            bat 'echo "hello" > src\\test-doc-1\\file1.txt'
            bat 'echo "world" > src\\test-doc-2\\file2.txt'
            bat '''
            for /d %%a in (src\\*-doc*) do (
              robocopy /r:0 /w:0 /e %%a dst\\%%~nxa
            )
            IF %%ERRORLEVEL%% LEQ 8 exit 0
            '''
         }
      }
   }
}
```

(Running Jenkins 2.190.3 if that's any help.)

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: Added an example pipeline to the question!

Comment: @JosefZ Wow, you may be right, that's probably it! Talk about a red herring :)